# React-native: Strict mode issue on certain libs?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am hitting the following issue when requiring certain libraries:

`java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: SyntaxError: Strict mode does not allow function declarations in a lexically nested statement.`

It happens on

1. `xmldom`: https://github.com/jindw/xmldom. In fact it happens on a recently setup environment and there is no problem on any other computers.
2. `jsdom`: I am trying to replace xmldom with jsdom and hit this issue on jsdom also.

It seems there is no existing discussion in RN area. Anyone knows what is happening?

Environment: RN 0.21 + Node 4.2.2 + Windows 7 Android Environment

Comment: Hey, I am getting same issue, did you found any fix for this ?

Comment: Not really. After that we used another PC to do RN work...