# React Native: SyntaxError: Strict mode does not allow function declarations in a lexically nested statement

Tags: ios, react-native

I've started getting this error on iOS after upgrading from React Native 0.22.2 and upgrading a few plugins.  I've tried downgrading and reinstalling everything but I can't get rid fix it.  Anyone else encountered this:

```
SyntaxError: Strict mode does not allow function declarations in a lexically nested statement.
```

#### Update #1:

In addition to reverting the modules I've commented out any `'use strict';`

One of the things I updated was npm and node.  I'm running node v5.3.0 and npm v3.8.3.  I don't remember what versions I had...

#### Update #2:

There are the modules I'm using in react native:

```
"dependencies": {
  "deep-freeze": "github:substack/deep-freeze",
  "react": "^0.14.7",
  "react-native": "^0.22.2",
  "react-native-activity-view": "^0.2.8",
  "react-native-animated-progress-bar": "^1.0.0",
  "react-native-audio": "^1.0.0",
  "react-native-camera": "git+https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera.git",
  "react-native-device-info": "^0.9.1",
  "react-native-fs": "^1.2.0",
  "react-native-html-to-pdf": "^0.1.2",
  "react-native-in-app-utils": "^2.3.0",
  "react-native-mail": "^0.2.4",
  "react-native-passcode-auth": "^1.0.0",
  "react-native-router-flux": "^2.3.13",
  "react-native-save-asset-library": "^1.0.0",
  "react-native-touch-id": "^1.2.4",
  "react-native-transfer": "^1.0.2",
  "react-native-utils": "^1.0.1",
  "react-native-webkit-localstorage-reader": "^1.0.0",
  "react-redux": "^3.1.2",
  "redux": "^3.0.5",
  "redux-thunk": "^2.0.1"
}
```

#### Update #3

With the thought that downgrading to React Native 0.21.0 would fix this problem I did the following:

1. Deleted the `node_modules` folder
2. Changed package.json's react-native version from 0.22.2 to 0.21.0 and removed the react entry (I think that's only a requirement for 0.22.2).
3. Ran `npm install`
4. Ran `npm start --reset-cache`
5. Opened xcode and ran the app on the simulator.

Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error.  Just to make sure it wasn't something external to my project I created a brand new react-native project and it ran fine (even with react native 0.22.2).  So it's something to do with my project but I can't for the life of me figure out what I did to cause this.  :(

Comment: You can try clearing the packager cache (npm start -- --reset-cache) it should make it work again after downgrading.

Comment: @Tom Krones, Could you solve the issue? If so, would you please post the solution?

Comment: @JanicDuplessis when I write "npm start -- --reset-cache", node says it is missing start script?

Answer (score -1):

This error happens because babel now adds 'use strict' to all modules. And it doesn't allow defining a function inside a lexical block like `if`

If the error comes from a library you could try to find which one cause it and add it to a `.babelignore` file.

You can also disable strict mode completely by using a `.babelrc` file with

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "syntax-async-functions",
    "syntax-class-properties",
    "syntax-trailing-function-commas",
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-es2015-arrow-functions",
    "transform-es2015-block-scoping",
    "transform-es2015-classes",
    "transform-es2015-computed-properties",
    "transform-es2015-constants",
    "transform-es2015-destructuring",
    ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs", { "strict": false, "allowTopLevelThis": true }],
    "transform-es2015-parameters",
    "transform-es2015-shorthand-properties",
    "transform-es2015-spread",
    "transform-es2015-template-literals",
    "transform-flow-strip-types",
    "transform-object-assign",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-react-display-name",
    "transform-react-jsx",
    "transform-regenerator",
    ["transform-es2015-for-of", { "loose": true }]
  ]
}
```

Note: make sure to clear the packager cache (`npm start -- --reset-cache`) to make sure all the transforms are run again.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Is "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs" an example of a plugin that you are disabling strict mode on or will that disable it for all plugins?  I tried creating a .babelrc file but OSX wouldn't let me, something about files starting with a "." are reserved for the OS.  This https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/#use-via-package-json talks about adding babel options to package.json so I did but after running ```npm start --reset-cache``` it didn't do anything.  I wish the error was more specific.  I have no idea wether the bad code is mine or from a react native module.

Comment: `transform-es2015-modules-commonjs` is the plugin that adds 'use strict' to every module automaticly, by passing the option `strict: false` it won't do it anymore. Not sure why you can't create a .babelrc file but you can always use `touch .babelrc` in a terminal to create it. Do you use any other library than react-native? If you don't the error should be in your code. I agree the error message is really bad, not sure if there is anything we can do to improve that :(.

Comment: Cool.  I didn't know about the```touch``` command, that created the file with no problems.  Unfortunately, it didn't fix the issue though.  I removed the package.json changes I made but removing strict mode in the ```.babelrc``` and running ```npm start --reset-cache``` didn't do it.  I added the list of modules I use in this app above (it's a long list).  I guess I could delete them all and see if it builds then add them back one at a time...

Comment: Apparently overriding plugins doesn't work propery, not sure why it worked last time I tested that. You can try specifying all the plugins that are in the react-native babel preset. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I'll check with the react-native team to see if we want to revert back to not using strict mode by default since it can cause issues like this that are hard to find and can be caused by libraries, at least until overiding a babel plugin config works properly.

Comment: Thanks, that would be great!  Is a v0.22 issue?  If I downgrade to v0.21 will I not have this problem?

Comment: Yes it is only in 0.22

Comment: I just added update #3 to my question above.  It might not be react native 0.22.2, right?

Comment: You need to run `npm start -- --reset-cache` Note the extra `--` is important or it won't work. It should work when downgrading to 0.21.

Comment: I am hitting this one specific libraries on 0.21. My question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36215888/react-native-strict-mode-issue-on-certain-libs