# SyntaxError: Strict mode does not allow function declarations in a lexically nested statement

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

After upgrading from React Native 0.18 to 0.22 for Android, I have started to get the following error:

```
Got JS Exception: SyntaxError: Strict mode does not allow function declarations in a lexically nested statement.
```

It crashes the app at start app, and it is impossible to start debugging.

As suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36230872/react-native-syntaxerror-strict-mode-does-not-allow-function-declarations-in-a), I have tried to remove all 'use strict' manually as well as using build script:

```
gulp.task('transform-android', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.tasks.androidjs.src)
  .pipe(envify({NATIVE: true}))
  .pipe(babel({ 
    "stage": 0,
    blacklist: ["useStrict"]
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(config.root.dest, config.tasks.androidjs.dest)));
});
```

There is no 'use strict' anymore in the generated code.
However, I am still getting the exact same error.
I am using babel v5.8.3.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "xodo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "events": "^1.1.0",
    "firebase": "^2.3.1",
    "flux": "^2.0.1",
    "immutable": "3.7.3",
    "jwt-decode": "^1.4.0",
    "linkifyjs": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "promise-queue": "^2.2.3",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-immutable-proptypes": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native": "^0.22.2",
    "react-native-invertible-scroll-view": "^0.2.0",
    "reqwest": "^1.1.5",
    "rsvp": "^3.0.18",
    "unbounce": "^0.1.0",
    "xmldom": "^0.1.22"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^5.8.3",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^5.3.0",
    "gulp-envify": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-less2js": "0.0.3",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-replace": "^0.5.4",
    "gulp-sequence": "^0.4.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  }
}
```

Below is the full stacktrace of the error:

```
Got JS Exception: SyntaxError: Strict mode does not allow function declarations in a lexically nested statement.
03-29 15:15:01.567 2047-2109/com.xodo.pdf.reader E/unknown:React: Exception in native call from JS
                                                                  com.facebook.react.bridge.JSExecutionException: SyntaxError: Strict mode does not allow function declarations in a lexically nested statement. (http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:32356)
                                                                      at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactBridge.loadScriptFromFile(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$2.loadScript(JSBundleLoader.java:58)
                                                                      at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$2.call(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:146)
                                                                      at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$2.call(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:137)
                                                                      at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$1.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:73)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                      at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:184)
                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: And you don't have any function declarations inside of if/else or for blocks?

Comment: I am sharing same backend code with React JS, which does have 'use strict', and works fine on browser. Only having issue when upgraded to RN v0.22 for Android.

Comment: I am hitting same issue and it happens in xmldom (dom.js line 17). If you want to confirm you can download the bundle file and check line 32356.

Answer (score 7):

problem appears in one of the core files. pull request is alredy created for react-native but you can make changes by yourself as workaround

> open node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\InitializeCore.js line 112
>
> change function handleError(e, isFatal) to var handleError = function(e, isFatal)
>
> then do npm start -- --reset-cache

you can find more information at https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11389

Comment: Worked like charm! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your problem but more of a concept or reason behind the error.

`When an inner function is defined in a block rather than function body it will give SyntaxError. ES5 disallows function declarations on blocks (except function bodies). On the other hand, ES2015 (ES6) has relaxed this restriction.`

Here is ESLint rule [no-inner-declaration](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-inner-declarations)